# Spacy EntityRuler is not giving proper results with regular expression pattern

Tags: python, spacy

I am working on Spacy EntityRuler pattern matching for one of my projects. I am not getting regex matching results. Below are the details:

```
regexText = r'[0-9 ]*(((?<=[0-9 ])/|\.)[0-9 ]{1,2})?(kg|kilo|gm|dz|doz|dozen|lt|ltr|litre|liter|packet|piece|ml|slice)s?'
    nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    ruler1 = EntityRuler(nlp, overwrite_ents=True)
    patterns = [{"label": "FRT", "pattern": [{'LOWER' : {'REGEX': regexText}}]}]
    ruler1.add_patterns(patterns)
    nlp.add_pipe(ruler1)
    doc1 = nlp(".5kg Apple 3kg opening its first big office 500gm in San Francisco.")
    print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc1.ents])

OUTPUT: 
[('kg', 'FRT'), ('Apple', 'ORG'), ('kg', 'FRT'), ('first', 'ORDINAL'), ('500gm', 'FRT'), ('San Francisco', 'GPE')]

Expected Output:
[('.5kg','FRT'),('Apple', 'ORG'), ('3kg','FRT'), ('first', 'ORDINAL'), ('500gm', 'FRT'), ('San Francisco', 'GPE')]
```

if u compare outputs, I am not getting .5kg and 3kg as 'FRT' even though I have included them in the regex. I mean numbers are not getting included. Only for '500gm' I am seeing the correct output

Comment: EntityRuler matches based on tokens, where each word is a token.  Because of its last two characters, which match end of string, your regular expression will match every token, because every token has an end.

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried removing last two characters but now it is not recognizing matching tokens. Below is the output I got after removing last two chars.          
 [('1kg', 'QUANTITY'), ('Apple', 'ORG'), ('3kg', 'QUANTITY'), ('first', 'ORDINAL'), ('500gm', 'FAC'), ('San Francisco', 'GPE')]

Comment: And isn't that just about perfect?

Comment: You didn't show us ORG, ORDINAL, FAC or GPE, so we can't comment on how they might conflict.

Comment: Since I have a regex pattern, I would expect '1kg', '3kg' and '500gm' to be labeled as 'QTY'. But it is not showing up like that. I even tried with nlp.add_pipe(ruler1, before='ner') and with this I am getting results like below: [('kg', 'QTY'), ('Apple', 'ORG'), ('3', 'CARDINAL'), ('kg', 'QTY'), ('first', 'ORDINAL'), ('500gm', 'QTY'), ('San Francisco', 'GPE')].. Here I would expect 3 to be combined with kg and show as ('3kg','QTY')

Comment: It's impossible to help you.  In your second comment, you said you got ('3kg','QUANTITY').  But now you say that's not what you get.  Which is it?  If YOU didn't include the ORG, CARDINAL, and ORDINAL rules, where did they come from? Is it "QTY' or "QUANTITY"?  Remember, if '3' matches the CARDINAL rule first, that wins. 
 It will never try any later rules.  Order matters.  Perhaps you should try your question again, with consistent results.

Comment: I am so sorry if I had confused u. I will rephrase the question.

Comment: @TimRoberts I hope my question is clear to u now. Can you please try to help me out now. I am still learning Python and NLP.

Comment: It's clear why the ".5kg" didn't match.  Your regex only recognizes a dot that has a digit in front of it.  I don't know what you're trying to do with the first 35 characters or so.  Why not just say "any sequence of digits or dots", `r"[0-9.]*(kg|kilo|gm...)"`.